# Palo Alto Layer 7

Tags: firewall, troubleshooting, acl, palo-alto

I've got the following error for a security policy in PA 3020:

```
L7 processing  ;  ctd error bypass
```

I tried Googling, but I couldn't find a solution.

Does anyone knows the meaning of this?

The issue is that  the packet with identical 5 tuple sometimes does not match the configured policy.